# what is $\dim \{f\in P_n|T(f)=f\}$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $P_n$ be polynomials of degree $\leq2n$ on $\mathbb{R}$.Clearly $P_n$ is a finite dimensional vector space.Let
$$ 
T(f)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{(x^2-y^2)\pi}\cos(2\pi yx)f(y)dy
$$
It's easy to show that $T$ maps $P_n$ to itself.

The problem is what is $\dim \{f\in P_n|T(f)=f\}$.

My idea:

Suppose $f(x)=x^k$, we can observe that $T(x^k)=0$ when $k$ is odd. When $k$ is even, by Fourier transformation,I prove that

$$
T(f)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{(x^2-y^2+2ixy)\pi}f(y)dy=\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^k}e^{x^2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{\mathrm{d}x^k}e^{-\pi x^2}
$$
When $k$ is even, it's easy to prove $T(x^k)$ is a polynominal with degree $k$, and its items are only even items.

And let $\{x^k\}_{k=0}^{n}$ be a basis. We can write $T$ as matrix, which is a upper triangular matrix with diagonal $\{1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,\cdots\}$, so I guess the answer is $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor+1$,but I can't prove it. I calculated $n=2$, and the answer is right.

Comment: Did you mean $n=1$ and hence the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $2$? Anyway, try to use the induction to see if you are guessing right. The basic step is proven since you have calculated the case $n=2$ (maybe $n=1$?). Perhaps you need to check to cases separately, namely when $n/2$ is an integer and when $n/2$ is not.

Comment: @InsideOut，when $n=1$, the answer is trival, I caculated the condition n=2,T is a 5*5 matrix, and the anser is 2.

Comment: @InsideOut, and Thank you for helping edit my question.

Comment: $\{f\in P_n\,|\, T(f)=f\}$ is the eigenspace relative to the eigenvector $1$, isn't it? So it is sufficient to compute the geometric multiplicity.

Comment: Yes, T is an upper triangular matrix with diagonal $\{1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,\cdots\}$, so its algbratic multiplicity is$\lfloor n/2 \rfloor+1$

Comment: But when $n=2$ the main diagonal is $(1,0,-1,0)$ and the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda=1$ is $1$.. Am I missing something? Maybe the right one $\lfloor \frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor$

Comment: When $n=2$ , the dimension of $P_n$ is 5 with the bisis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109097/discussion-between-insideout-and-vfenux).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $ \mathcal{F}f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-2\pi i x y} f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y $ for the Fourier transform, and let $\mathcal{M}f(x) = e^{-\pi x^2}f(x)$. Also let

$$ E_n = \{ f \in P_n : \text{$f$ is even} \}. $$

Then it is easy to check that:

1. If $f \in P_n$ solves $Tf = f$, then $f \in E_n$.
2. For $f \in E_n$, we have $Tf = \mathcal{M}^{-1}\mathcal{F}\mathcal{M}f$.
3. Equip $E_n$ with the inner product $\langle f, g \rangle := \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline{\mathcal{M}f(x)}\mathcal{M}g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $. Then by the Plancherel's Theorem,

   $$ \langle Tf, Tg \rangle
   = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline{\mathcal{F}\mathcal{M}f(x)}\mathcal{F}\mathcal{M}g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
   = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \overline{\mathcal{M}f(x)}\mathcal{M}g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
   = \langle f, g \rangle, $$

   and so, $T$ restricted to $E_n$ is an isometry with respect to this inner product.

This proves that $T$ restricted to $E_n$ is diagonalizable. So the geometric multiplicity of $1$ coincide the algebraic multiplicity of $1$, which is $\lfloor n/2\rfloor + 1$ as computed by other users.

Comment: That‘s really amazing. Thank you for wonderful answer!